# Find the number of while loops in a program using regex

Tags: java, regex

Hi I need a regex to evaluate the condition of a while loop. Upto now I built something like this.

```
String WhileCalc="while\\s*\\(+\\)+\\s*\\{";
```

This evaluate while(){ types. But To evaluate inside the conditions cant I use this approach every time.

```
String whileCalc="while\\s*\\(+.*\\)+\\s*\\{";
```

Is this a good method to evaluate a while loop?

Comment: Using a parser to get a syntactic tree would prevent a lot of headaches.

Comment: You should probably precise the language you want to par... to analyze. Is it Java ?

Comment: Yes I'm programming using Java. Are there any materials that I can use to learn it? Isn't regular expression a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex examples that you wrote might catch things that you don't want, for example a variable like

`String[] tmpWhile = new String();`

Since while is a [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) you can simply count the number of occurrences of `\bwhile\b`

**UPDATE**
If you want to ignore comments - then you can't use regex - you'll have to use/build a parser.

The following is a (poor*) example to such a parser. I used this class to parse itself and got a total count of 2 valid `while`s.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Play  {


    public static void parse(String classFile) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(classFile));
        try {
            String line = br.readLine();
            // a comment with a while "while" and 'while'
            int total = 0;
            while (line != null) { // just a dumb comment in the same line as the while
                if (line.indexOf("//") > -1) {
                    line = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("//"));
                }
                if (line.indexOf("/*") > -1) { // comment-starts
                    line = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("/*"));
                    total += checkIfValidWhileInLine(line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                    // ignore comments like /* ... */
                    while (line.indexOf("*/") < 0) {
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }
                    line = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("*/"));
                }
                total += checkIfValidWhileInLine(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(total);
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }

    }

    private static int checkIfValidWhileInLine(String line) {
        if (line.matches("^.*?\\bwhile\\b.*$")) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        parse("/Users/alfasi/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/src/Play.java");
    }
}
```

- This implementation is for demo only, I wrote that it's poor because you can "break" this implementation by adding edge-cases that are not being handled in `parse()`

Comment: But I feel, if word while is used in a comment doesn't it too count as a while loop?

Comment: From the original regex it looks as if the condition of the while is wanted. Also, wouldn't it be hard (impossible?) to exlude while from strings and comments using regex?

Comment: Could you please explain me something more about parser. Yes I don't want to account comments. Rather than that counting the keyword while is enough for me.

Comment: What exactly do you need explanation about ?

Comment: About a way to ignore comments and count number of while loops. You had mentioned to build a parser. Could you explain bit more about it?

Comment: Ahhh its really clear. :) Well so far I have read the files taking as a whole bulk of String from the database. So to follow this approach (Line by line read-(br.readLine()))do I need to write the String to  an internal file and read line by line.

Comment: @user3789200 if all you need is to count the `while`s then you don't have to write it to file - you can do the counting in-memory.

Comment: BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new StringReader(file_content));
did what I wanted and alfasin it works now. I'm so happy. Thanks alot for your precious help... :)

Answer (score 1):

Computer science says that programming languages are more complex than what can be parsed by a regular expression (Chomsky Type 2 vs. Chomsky type 2, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy. That means, there is no regular expression that can understand any number of nestings of while statements. Of course, you can use a regular expression to find all while statements regardless of the nesting, if that is what you want to accomplish.